# Applying a Function to a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, kdb

I am new to KDB and am currently getting to grips with dictionaries.I have a dictionary of the format

```
UK|34 55 6 16
Italy|44 78 43 12
Iran|21 4 2
```

How would I create and apply a function to my dictionary so that an average may be calculated for each key?

Comment: Please post some code you've tried to  implement along with your question. We are happy to guide you along a path with code you've tried to write, but we are less inclined to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q)avgFunc:{sum[x]%count x} /create function
q)/apply the function to each dictionary value
q)avgFunc each  `UK`Italy`Iran!(34 55 6 16;44 78 43 12;21 4 2)
UK   | 27.75
Italy| 44.25
Iran | 9
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/each/

The each adverb applies the function to each value of the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Like @jomahony says, `function each dict` is what you're looking for.

In some rare examples - if your function works on lists of lists - you don't even need the each, e.g

```
q)1+d
UK   | 35 56 7 17
Italy| 45 79 44 13
Iran | 22 5 3
q)
q)reciprocal d
UK   | 0.02941176 0.01818182 0.1666667 0.0625
Italy| 0.02272727 0.01282051 0.02325581 0.08333333
Iran | 0.04761905 0.25 0.5
```

But most custom function and likely most built-ins (including avg) require it

Comment: Maybe not that rare? Any atomic function works on lists of lists by definition, `1+`, `reciprocal`, `2 xexp reciprocal` etc. will work just fine.